# How can I create a user on Ubuntu with the same permissions as the initial user?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, user-accounts

I want to create a user account on an Ubuntu Lucid system that has the same permissions as the original user account that was created during the install process. How can I do this? Imaginary bonus points for a command-line solution, but I'll accept a graphical solution as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **adduser** command to create a new user, with the groups from [this question.](https://serverfault.com/questions/11488/what-are-the-default-groups-assigned-to-the-first-user-in-ubuntu-server)

```
sudo adduser {username} adm,dialout,cdrom,floppy,audio,dip,video,plugdev,scanner,netdev,lpadmin,powerdev,admin
```